# New files are always empty when creating a new class in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When creating cocoa touch classes, the new file is always empty:

```
import Cocoa

class UpcomingEvents: UITableViewController {

}
```

How can I set up Xcode to allow for everything to populate with the tableView override functions automatically upon creation of file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You code shows that you created Cocoa classes not Cocoa Touch. When creating file choose [image]iOS and then select Cocoa Touch Classes and create file sub class of UITableViewController. Then you will get as you expected.